# Fullcalendar scheduler v5 auto refresh events

Tags: json, webhooks, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

Is it possible to 'push' new events to fullcalendar scheduler without page refresh?

My source for events is JSON feed. So I would like a new event to appear in the calendar once another user enters it. There should be a listener/webhook to the json feed and if recognizes a change in the data, it should trigger calendar to refetch events.

Is something like this possible?

I found a way to do it:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var source = new EventSource('sse.php')
        source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            //console.log(e.data);
            if (e.data != 'doNotUpdate'){
                calendar.refetchEvents();
            }
        }, false);
        
    }
```

However, the sse.php, which is the script running on server and checks for new events in database table, is probably being triggered every second or every few seconds and returning doUpdate or doNotUpdate. I am not sure if this is ok? To many requests on MySQL? Should I set it up differently?

Comment: You'd need (separately to fullCalendar) a Server-Sent Events or Websockets implementation which can push the data from the server to the client. Then you can add the data to the calendar in one of the normal ways.

Comment: Can you provide me any useful link with more about how to implement Server-Sent Events or Websockets?

Comment: You can find it easily with simple online searches I think. If you don't succeed, I might have time later to search. But better to find something, try it and then ask more if you get stuck

Comment: P.s. If you only need the real-time messages to go one way (from server to client) then server sent events is likely to be simpler to implement

Comment: ADyson, I have updated my question. Somehow I have managed to integrate server sent events into fullcalendar, but not sure if I have done it properly. I am worried about to many requests to MySQL, checking for new data. It currently works when tested only by me, but if more users would open the sse channel, I am afraid something will crash.

Comment: Well, instead of running refetch events every time - which I assume causes another request to the server, why not just send the newly added event(s) directly in the SSE message and add them to the calendar individually?

Comment: But yes, using the SSE will increase resource usage of your system - bandwidth, webserver capacity, and database server capacity. That's an inevitable consequence of adding this kind of functionality. Even if you optimise it every way you can, usage will still go up. So you need to factor that in when looking at the ability of your application to scale to the predicted number of users. And then you need to do some performance testing - I can't tell you what exactly will happen due to your changes...if you're worried, test it.